# Why does the best performing adapter-based parameter-efficient fine-tuning depend on the language model being fine-tuned?

Tags: natural-language, language-models, domain-adaptation, llm

https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.01933 shows that the best performing adapter-based parameter-efficient fine-tuning depends on the language model being fine-tuned:

[image]

E.g., LORA is the best adapter for LlaMa-7B, while S-adapter is the best adapter for BLOOM-7.1B.

Why does the best performing adapter-based parameter-efficient fine-tuning depend on the language model being fine-tuned?